# try/except vs validate the data while inserting to avoid "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint"?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Which is the better option for performance?

Python try/except?

```
try:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO date (iyear, imonth, iday) VALUES (?,?,?)',year, month, day)
except Exception:
    pass
```

or validate the data in database?

```
cursor.execute('IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM date where iyear = ? and imonth = ? and iday = ?) INSERT INTO date (iyear, imonth, iday) VALUES (?,?,?)',year, month, day,year, month, day)
```

Actually I am not sure if using `if not exists` is the better option to validate the data. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: It is better to measure than to guess.

Comment: It depends how often you'll have dups. [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) to determine the tipping point in your environment if performance particularly important to you. Also be aware you'll have a race condition unless you use a transaction and locking hints.